# C - Swap first and last element in singly linked list

Tags: c, swap, singly-linked-list

What i'm trying to do, is swap the first and last elements of a singly linked list. So far i have the following code, where i create a list and add some numbers to it. My problem is at the swapElements1 function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int number;
    struct node *next;
};

void addNodeSingle(struct node **head, int num, int thesi) //Function to insert new node at the beginning or the end of the list, depending on the value of "thesi"
{
    if (*head == NULL)
    {
        struct node *current;
        current = (struct node*) malloc (1*sizeof(struct node));
        current -> number = num;
        current -> next = NULL;
        *head = current;
    }

    else
    {
        if (thesi == 0)
        {
            struct node *current;
            current = (struct node*) malloc (1*sizeof(struct node));
            current -> number = num;
            current -> next = *head;
            *head = current;
        }

        else
        {
            struct node *current, *temp;
            current = (struct node*) malloc (1*sizeof(struct node));
            current -> number = num;
            temp = *head;
            while (temp -> next != NULL)
                temp = temp -> next;

            temp -> next = current;
            current -> next = NULL;
        }
    }
}

void displayList(struct node **head) //Function to display the list
{
    struct node *current;
    if(*head == NULL)
        printf("I lista einai adeia!\n");

    else
    {
    current= *head ;
        while(current != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d ",current -> number);
            current = current -> next;
        }
    }
}

void swapElements1(struct node **head) //(not working)Function to swap first and last element of the list
{
    struct node *current, *temp;
    current = temp = *head;

    while(current != NULL)
    {
        temp = current;
        current = current -> next;
    }

    *head = (*head)->next;
    *head = temp;
    current = NULL;
}

int main()
{
    struct node *head;
    head = NULL;

    addNodeSingle(&head,5,1);
    addNodeSingle(&head,6,1);
    addNodeSingle(&head,2,0);
    addNodeSingle(&head,7,0);
    addNodeSingle(&head,8,0);

    printf("List is: ");
    displayList(&head);
    swapElements1(&head);
    printf("\nNew list is: ");
    displayList(&head);
}
```

The output i get is:

List is: 8 7 2 5 6

New list is: 6

What i need is:

List is: 8 7 2 5 6

New list is: 6 7 2 5 8

Here's a [demo](http://ideone.com/ztzJ4h)

Comment: You have four pointers to update: the head, the next pointer in the first item, the next pointer in the second-to-last item, and the next pointer in the last item.

Comment: Have you considered the straight forward swapping of the data, instead of the nodes? Or is this a school exercise which requires it?

Comment: @WeatherVane Unfortunately, I want to swap the nodes and not just the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is clearly wrong:

```
*head = (*head)->next;
*head = temp;
```

That just overwrites the previous value with the value of `temp`. The first statement may as well not even be there.

You fundamentally need two swaps (technically one plus an assignment and termination)

- The pointers pointing to the two nodes
- The two nodes `next` pointers

The latter of these isn't technically needed, but a direct assignment *is* needed, and the new tail needs to have it's `next` set to null to terminate the new list.

A full example is shown below, liberally commented to hopefully give expose the algorithm of what is going on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

void swapFirstAndLast(struct node **head)
{
    // don't bother unless we have a list of at least two nodes
    if (!*head || !(*head)->next)
        return;

    // start with the head's next pointer (the second node in the list)
    struct node **pp = &(*head)->next;

    // walk the pointer-to-pointer down the list, each time grasping
    //  the next node's "next" pointer address until we reach a node
    //  whose 'next' is NULL. When that happens, `pp` will hold the
    //  address of the pointer pointing to the last node in the list
    while (*pp && (*pp)->next)
        pp = &(*pp)->next;

    // swap the pointer held in *head with *pp
    struct node *tmp = *head;
    *head = *pp;
    *pp = tmp;

    // save new head's next pointer to be the old head's next
    (*head)->next = (*pp)->next;

    // and finally, terminate the list.
    (*pp)->next = NULL;
}

void print_list(const struct node *head)
{
    while (head)
    {
        printf("%d ", head->data);
        head = head->next;
    }
    fputc('\n', stdout);
}

int main()
{
    struct node *head = NULL, **pp = &head;
    for (int i=1; i<=5; ++i)
    {
        *pp = malloc(sizeof **pp);
        (*pp)->data = i;
        pp = &(*pp)->next;
    }
    *pp = NULL;

    print_list(head);

    swapFirstAndLast(&head);

    print_list(head);
}
```

**Output**

```
1 2 3 4 5 
5 2 3 4 1
```

I've left the list cleanup for you (no doubt you have such an algorithm already coded). The crux of this is how to use pointers to pointers to manipulate the linked list's pointers; not just a bunch of temp pointers. I strongly encourage you to single-step through the exchange function in a debugger, watching what is happening with each step along the way.

Comment: Hmm, your code is working and it solves my problem. But i can't really understand what you are doing exactly. Can you elaborate more? Because i need to do the same on a doubly linked list and on a circular linked list.

Comment: Honestly, I can't. I wrote a small novel in the code comments and the post already. Between that and taking the initiative to do what I described in the last sentence of the post (single stepping in a debugger and examining variables to see *exactly* what is going on), there should be enough to understand the algorithm. If not, you may need to refamiliarize yourself with pointers, and as you can see in the code, pointers to pointers.

Comment: And what would the time complexity of that function be? Is it the same as a doubly linked list and a circular linked list?

Comment: @user3120283 swapping first/last in a single-linked single-entrance (no tail pointer, only head pointer) is O(n); sequential scan is required (as shown here). A double linked list with dual-entrance (both head and tail pointers) is O(1), as no sequential scan is required. A circular linked list has no first/last, so the question is somewhat meaningless in that context. However they *usually* are implemented as double-linked lists, and as such, given a head pointer, the previous pointed-to-node is swappable in O(1) as well.

Answer (score 1):

WhozCraig's answer is already perfect, but perhaps you may want to see your own code with some adjustments. Basically, what I did was to stop your search for the last element one iteration earlier, so that temp would stop at 5 and current at 6. Also, you have to make four changes with pointers, like WhozCraig did.
Here is your code, modified slightly:

```
void swapElements1(struct node **head) //(not working)Function to swap first and last element of the list
{
    struct node *current, *temp;
    current = temp = *head;

    while(current->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = current;
        current = current -> next;
    }
    temp->next = *head;
    current->next = (*head)->next;
    (*head)->next = NULL;
    *head = current;
}
```

That worked on my machine. I changed your while loop condition from current to current->next and made the correct "pointer changes". These pointer changes are hard to explain, usually I make them on paper first and then write them in code.

Comment: Can you provide me with a visual representation of the above? That would be extremely helpful. Now i'm trying to do the same for a doubly linked list and a circular linked list but i have no success so far. [This](http://ideone.com/aVnwEu) is what i got for the doubly linked list but i get an error.

Comment: Hello! Here you go, I have made a visual representation of each command. Here is the [link](https://postimg.org/image/3x5mnpswz/).

Comment: Hmm, the visual presentation really helps,but i still can't figure out how to do the same thing with a doubly linked list or a circular linked list. Can you help? [This](http://ideone.com/00gEGb) is what i have.

Answer (score 0):

Already people have answered correctly, if anyone of you has trouble in dealing with double pointers, refer to the below answer.

```
void swap(){
if (!head || !(head -> next)){
    return;
}
node* tail = head;
while(tail -> next -> next != NULL){
    tail = tail -> next;
}
node* tmp = head;
head = tail -> next;
tail -> next = tmp;
head -> next = tmp -> next;
tmp -> next = NULL;
return;
}
```

I  have declared the head pointer as a global variable(Thats why I don't need to play around with double pointers inside the functions).

Below is my structure definition for your reference

```
typedef struct node{
int data;
struct node *next;
}node;
```